# Communication between controllers through $window.location.href

Tags: angularjs

I have the following statements in controller 1:

```
$scope.field1 = "abcd";
$window.location.href = 'main.html';
```

Then, in `main.html` I have controller 2, and need to have access to the value of field1.

Is this possible using a service or factory, as `$window.location.href` will replace the scope? will $broadcast/$emit work in this case?

**UPDATE**

I tried with a singleton service calling `set` in controller 1 and `get` in controller 2, but the variable in controller 2 is still null

```
app.service('singleton', function() {

      var myField1 = null;

      this.set = function(f) {
          myField1 = f;
      };

      this.get = function() {
          return myField1;
      };
```

Comment: Are you using angular routing?

Comment: yes, but in this specific case I need to use $window.location.href

Comment: Thats fine but you should still be able to pass the variable as a routeParam.

Comment: I also would go for the routeParam, never allow controllers to modify other scopes.

Comment: Is it possible to replace a whole page using routeParam/routeProvider or only partials in the templateURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 different pages, like:

```
<html>
page1
</html>

<html>
page2
</html>
```

Then they are completely independent, so i.e. angular will be loaded separately in page1 and page2 - you can not make javascript connection between them. All js objects are just discarded when you change url. So you can use param page1.html?param=value, cookies, localStorage (2 latest for same domain).

Thats why most angular apps are one page - you may see different paths in url, but this is still just one page (i.e. index.html). In this case you can connect them using angular service, $rootScope (which is actually just another service too) or using params in ui-router.